# Mootools 'Uncaught TypeError: Property 'container' of object #<Object> is not a function' error when accordion added

Tags: debugging, mootools, javascript, mootools-more

I'm working with a site developed by an external developer. I've noticed the code they use for accordions only supports a fixed number of accordion items per page (even though their CMS can create an unlimited amount of items marked as being displayed accordion-style). I'm trying to tidy this up to avoid confusing my colleagues later down the line.

I'm trying to add a standard Mootools more accordion, but when I add it to a page I get the error below:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'container' of object # is not a
>   function mootools-core-1.4.5-full-compat.js:683

[Here's an example page](http://www.aua.ac.uk/event-72-Development-and-Skills-Conference-.html) - the links in  tags below 'Session details - Click the titles below for more information on each session.' should all be accordions.

I'm calling this code at the bottom of my page from http://www.aua.ac.uk/scripts/accordion.js:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    new Fx.Accordion($$('#sub_left .accordion_heading'),$$('#sub_left .accordion_holder'), {
        opacity: 0,
        display: -1,
        alwaysHide: true
    });
});
```

Using these versions of Mootools (referenced at the top of the page in the head):

[mootools-core-1.4.5-full-compat.js](http://www.aua.ac.uk/scripts/mootools-core-1.4.5-full-compat.js) and [mootools-more-1.4.0.1.js](http://www.aua.ac.uk/scripts/mootools-more-1.4.0.1.js)

Here is a fiddle using those verions of mootools, a portion of the HTML from my page, and the same accordion code - and it's all working. I think there is a conflict somewhere on my full page but I can't work out where.

http://jsfiddle.net/bcfu2/5/

Does anyone have any idea how to either fix this, or where to start debugging it - other than removing code/links to JS files one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The js of microsoft creating some collision with mootools Array implements:

```
 <script src="/WebResource.axd?d=maKRZUGfDX1oNLvbjE5CVpp8Freqy1QYQvNjdATWoN2tEAP8BRYB9DDy6RYI9PQwhPak11VYG6N-fakPxQX9OdjCS0k1&amp;t=634604425351482412" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=WSd7pLxkPBvO2m8zwahAn--zWk9drBpRcPo6hiP5S6h3lc4U02xAjGNhWI80hxb4tjqMmAYSYPB7ziM6k7g74E-bBOiz7xRre8hSbGF4tJ2E6c8VeX-W4J-tQv1ZL10ruL5uPffOFyiUX3xZVWWQT_YClyI1&amp;t=ffffffffb868b5f4" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=bawOzJp1LF5Sj6rS_r-W75i2ouoWmFBvTNI9zqR0q_Lsf42KbPAaMTrPFSZ9jqam3zDWOHBUgNgKBDwGos_WSLyBOzTAzYVuGRRlgWxM0Jm-uc_fb8NPaprYxmDuvgVoemZKvN0bfNIpr2yzsXUjhCVB-0dFOF6qHbKXJEXRN_LWShmr0&amp;t=ffffffffb868b5f4" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If you remove those scripts you will see your code is working fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/V8WRM/

Comment: You're right, thank you very much. I had a feeling it would be something connected to ASP.NET. I tried the renaming suggestions [made in this bug tracker topic](https://mootools.lighthouseapp.com/projects/2706/tickets/1045-asp-net-bug) but they didn't work, so in the end I rewrote a basic accordion myself using Fx.Slide. What a waste of a few hours trying to debug this issue!

Comment: A word of advice: stay away from asp.net ;-)

Comment: Ha, I know. I'm a LAMP and jQuery man myself, but this is a site I maintain at work - it was purchased before I joined the organisation and had a chance to steer things towards an open-source route!

Comment: @Adidi, As Microsoft adds these scripts automatically how would one "remove" them?